# RegExp search in arrays

Tags: regex, replace

So I have found many topics about how to use regexp, but it al fails for my situation.
How I can search with a wildcard between [].
Below an example:

```
    <tag>
    <name>VS6/Application/VAR_Network/AccessPoints[1]/Nodes[1]/Input1</name>
    <resourceLocator>prot3://4?NS4|String||var|CODESYS Control RTE .Application.VAR_Network.AccessPoints[1].Nodes[1].Input1?boolean</resourceLocator>
    <refreshTime>500</refreshTime>
    <accessMode>READ-WRITE</accessMode>
    <active>false</active>
    <simulator>VRBL://OPC_VS6/CODESYS_OPC_UA_Server|Objects|DeviceSet|CODESYS Control RTE |Resources|Application|GlobalVars|VAR_Network|AccessPoints[1]/Nodes[1]/Input1?boolean</simulator>
    <enableScaling>false</enableScaling>
    <TAGLOCATOR>OPC UA Client:prot3:uid4:CODESYS_OPC_UA_Server|Objects|DeviceSet|CODESYS Control RTE |Resources|Application|GlobalVars|VAR_Network|AccessPoints[1]/Nodes[1]/Input1</TAGLOCATOR>
    <enableAudit subT="1" eventT="18">false</enableAudit>
</tag>
```

So I would like to search the following:

```
|AccessPoints[.*]/Nodes[.*]/Input1
```

Then replace it with:

```
|AccessPoints[.*]|Nodes[.*]|Input1
```

Of course, the number should be left the same after replace.
I have Notepad++ and UltraEdit.

Comment: I would not use regex to edit / parse xml. But if you insist, to match something between brackets: `\[.+\]`

Comment: If `|AccessPoints[.*]/Nodes[.*]/Input1` should be replaced globally regardless of where it is located, the fact that it is XML is not important.

Comment: Replace `(\|AccessPoints\[\d+])/(Nodes\[\d+])/(Input\d+)` with `$1|$2|$3`. If you need to specifically match `Item1`, not `Item2`, or `Item10`, replace `Input\d+` with `Input1\b`

Comment: I can't recommend using `.*` here, because it will match too much.

Answer (score 1):

This works after testing it against your example in Notepad++.
You may want to tighten-up that wildcard though to be more specific on what is allowed inside the square brackets.

```
Search: /AccessPoints\[(.*)\]/Nodes\[(.*)\]/Input1
Replace: |AccessPoints[$1]|Nodes[$2]|Input1
```